# Sqlite query for date sorting

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I need to get the sorted dates by query in SQLite that are in timestamp format

I tried this query but not works well

```
SELECT  * FROM  allmessages WHERE  TIMESTAMP <=  DATE('now','-365 day') AND  TIMESTAMP >=  DATE('now')  order by  TIMESTAMP  DESC
```

I need sorted dates like

*From today to before 1 year*

*From today to before 30 days*

*From today to before 7 days*

***These are the dates that are in DB***

[image]

Sory for bad english...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I've got:

```
SELECT *
FROM allmessages
WHERE timestamp <= strftime('%s', 'now')*1000
AND timestamp >= strftime('%s', 'now', '-365 days')*1000;
```

Some caveats:

Your timestamps seem to be in milliseconds since the epoch? I'm multiplying SQLite's internal timestamps by 1000 to reflect that.

You want dates between today and one year ago (2012)? If so, the above query is fine; if you wanted dates from today to one year from now (2014), flip the comparison operators.

I'm using SQLite's internal `rowid` column; you can move this to other databases by substituting that for your own id column.

[Here's a live SQL Fiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c9119/18)

Comment: Looks like java timestamps i.e. milliseconds since Jan 1 1970. So the multiplier should be 1000 not 100.

Comment: @laalto Looks like I missed a zero when copying data over. That does make *way* more sense to me. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it just be

```
SELECT  * FROM  allmessages WHERE  DATE(TIMESTAMP) >=  DATE('now','-365 day') AND   DATE(TIMESTAMP) <  DATE('now')  order by  TIMESTAMP  DESC
```

Comment: Then you need `date(timestamp)` instead of `*`.

Comment: @CL. Problem with that query is its not displaying any records. It shows empty and I need all the fields to give that objects to adapter

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  * FROM  allmessages WHERE  DATE(TIMESTAMP/1000, 'unixepoch') >=  DATE('now','-365 day') AND   DATE(TIMESTAMP/1000, 'unixepoch') <  DATE('now')  order by  TIMESTAMP  DESC
```

See there for more details (look for timestamp): http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Those dates are not in `unixepoch` since I tried it by using `SELECT datetime(1377175845000, 'unixepoch');` and also `SELECT DATE(1377175845000, 'unixepoch')` they shows wrong format. and the format converter shows proper dates [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/)

Comment: @Kartheek Just divide the timestamp by 1000 (edited the query).